# Iteration through array data

Tags: ruby, json, recursion, foreach

I have a JSON data which in the following format:

```
 [{
        "id": 1,
        "children": [{
                "id": 7,
                "children": [{
                        "id": 8,
                        "children": [{
                                "id": 4
                            }, {
                                "id": 5
                            }, {
                                "id": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id": 9
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 6
            }, {
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [{
                "id": 3
            }, {
                "id": 12
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 13
    }
]
```

The tree for this JSON data is:

[image]

I want to loop through all the nodes and extract the "id" of all data maintaining its parent child hierarchy. How can i do this using recursive function.

The idea is to parse the json structure in ruby.

Comment: That do you mean by "parent data"?

Comment: Update your question, and add the array that you want as a result with that sample of data, and I'll give you the code to do that within 5 or 10 minutes. Don't delete the question, its a valid question and I'll love to help you.

Comment: You need to write actually a javascript iteration algorithm to do that, I'll write one for you after dinner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just coded a node js code, you can still make it work on a browser in js, but you will need to download the underscore library [here](http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js).

```
_und = require('underscore');

data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "children": [{
                "id": 7,
                "children": [{
                        "id": 8,
                        "children": [{
                                "id": 4
                            }, {
                                "id": 5
                            }, {
                                "id": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id": 9
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 6
            }, {
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [{
                "id": 3
            }, {
                "id": 12
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 13
    }
]

function parse_tree_2(n) {
    return(_und.map(n, parse_tree));
}

function parse_tree(n) {
    if (n['children']) {
        return({id: n['id'], children: parse_tree_2(n['children'])});
    } else {
        return({id: n['id']});
    }
}

result = _und.map(data, parse_tree);

console.log("Result: %j", result);
```

You can put that into a file, and execute it with node (by download underscore with **nmp install node**).

On plain js it would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "children": [{
                "id": 7,
                "children": [{
                        "id": 8,
                        "children": [{
                                "id": 4
                            }, {
                                "id": 5
                            }, {
                                "id": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id": 9
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 6
            }, {
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [{
                "id": 3
            }, {
                "id": 12
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 13
    }
]

function parse_tree_2(n) {
    return(_.map(n, parse_tree));
}

function parse_tree(n) {
    if (n['children']) {
        return({id: n['id'], children: parse_tree_2(n['children'])});
    } else {
        return({id: n['id']});
    }
}

result = _.map(data, parse_tree);

console.log("Result: %j", result);

</script>
```

---

Ruby code:

```
require 'json'

data = <<EOF
[{
        "id": 1,
        "children": [{
                "id": 7,
                "children": [{
                        "id": 8,
                        "children": [{
                                "id": 4
                            }, {
                                "id": 5
                            }, {
                                "id": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id": 9
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 6
            }, {
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [{
                "id": 3
            }, {
                "id": 12
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 13
    }
]
EOF

json = JSON.parse(data)

def parse_tree(n)
  if n["children"]
    {id: n["id"], children: n['children'].map {|c| parse_tree(c)} }
  else
    {id: n["id"]}
  end
end


result = json.map {|n| parse_tree(n) }

puts result
```

Comment: can it be done in other server side language rather than using javascript.

Comment: ruby? or any other language?

Comment: ok, let me know if it worked, if it did, remember to select my answer as the right answer, and to give me a positive vote :)

Comment: Hello rorra, can you please do it in ruby?

Comment: I did that, check the last part of my code, I updated the answer with the ruby code